# Ranged archive retrievals for objects in S3 Glacier Deep Archive

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I'm working with some fairly large objects in S3, using the Glacier Deep Archive storage class. From time to time it's necessary for me to retrieve these objects to read small parts of the contents of the larger objects. For example, out of many TBs I need to read a few GB. I know the exact byte ranges I need to read.

I was initially excited to find that doing [ranged archive retrievals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/downloading-an-archive-two-steps.html#downloading-an-archive-range) is possible in AWS S3 Glacier, which (I've learned) is not equivalent to AWS S3. However, I understand that S3 objects in deep archive storage is (somehow) using AWS S3 Glacier in the background.

So my question is, is it possible to restore only parts of S3 objects in glacier/deep archive? Or, is it possible to access the underlying S3 Glacier vault for an S3 object?